# Android - Radio Button Not Showing its Text

Tags: android, xml, text, radio-button

My app has a radio button group as part of a RelativeLayout. My problem is that the RadioButtons are not showing their text. All I get is the buttons themselves.

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/setupTabLayout"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="#ffffff" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:baselineAligned="true" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" 
        android:text="Total Points" 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize = "30sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:paddingBottom="5px"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        ></TextView>

      <EditText android:id="@+id/editTextTotal" 
        android:text="" 
        android:digits="-0123456789."
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1" 
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1" 
    ></EditText>

    <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
    > 

        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radioButton1" 
            android:checked="true" 
            android:text="Points" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        ></RadioButton>

        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radioButton2" 
            android:text="Points" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton1" 
        ></RadioButton>

    </RadioGroup>   

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" 
        android:text="Points Per = " 
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize = "30sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5px"
        android:layout_above="@+id/numberPadLayoutContainer"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ></TextView>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/editTextPoints" 
        android:text="" 
        android:digits="-0123456789."
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2" 
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2" 
    ></EditText>

    <include layout="@layout/numerickeyboard" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any ideas why the text isn't showing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your `Layout` background is white and also the texts on the `RadioButtons` are white. They are displayed you just don't see them.

You can try and set `android:textColor="#000"` to make te texts black.

Comment: Ahhh... Well here is a duh moment. Interesting that the default color is white when it seems to be light gray for all of the other text controls. Thank you.  :-)